# Scrapy + Python : Crawler not saving to CSV

Tags: python, scrapy

[I am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJTT3.png)  - click to see the error

I have modified my code below and I am getting an error
**"csvwriter" is not defined**.Please help!!

```js
import scrapy
import csv

class MyprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "travel"
   allowed_domains = ["mytravelexp.com"]
   
   start_urls = [
      "http://www.mytravelexp.com",
   ]

   fields = ['Link']
   filename = "travel.csv"
   with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
   def parse(self, response):
    print(response.xpath('//a/@href').extract())
    csvwriter.writerows(print(response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()))
```

Comment: Why're you writing this directly inside the class and not inside a method or on top-level?

Comment: Sorry not clear ....pls suggest what is the correct code to fix it. Ps...I am a noob

Comment: When you don't need the class functionality (as it looks at least in the code of your question), remove `class MyprojectSpider(scrapy.Spider):` and unindent your code. (Or please provide the remaining code as well)

Comment: That is the whole code....I removed it....still getting error...pls check at your end

Comment: As I commented on your previous question, if you should work through the [`scrapy tutorial`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). It very clearly explains how to store scraped data. Please do that and then let us know if something isn't clear there.